# unicodedata.normalize() is not working using Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

HTML:

```
<tbody>
   <tr >
       <td> Tim Cook </td>
       <td class="wpsTableNrmRow" > Apple CEO </td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
       <td> Sundar Pichai </td>
       <td class="wpsTableNrmRow" > Google(CEO) </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Code:

```
applicationHeader = [td.text
                     for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableShdRow" and text()!=" "]')]
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Apple CEO' , 'Google(CEO)']  // Need to remove special characters.
```

I tried below code:

```
applicationHeader = [unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", td.text)
                     for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableShdRow" and text()!=" "]')]
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Apple CEO' , 'Google(CEO)'] // special characters are not removed
```

How to remove special characters using unicodedata?

I know that `td.text.replace(' ',"").replace("(","").replace(")","")` will work. but i don't want to use this method.

Comment: where you have found special character?? The output is string list and it should be like that.https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Comment: @Kunduk I want to remove "(", ")" and spaces between words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
applicationHeader =[re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', td.text) for td in webBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="wpsTableShdRow" and text()!=" "]')]
print(applicationHeader )
```

use regex , normalize is not to remove special characters

Comment: I can't use unicodedata.normalize() for removing special characters.in selenium.

Comment: I tried with Beautiful.soup, it was working fine.